# Can I automate State Plane to Lat/Lon conversion in CartoDB?

Tags: coordinate-system, carto

Reading this: [How do I convert State Plane coordinates to latitude-longitude?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16/how-do-i-convert-state-plane-coordinates-to-latitude-longitude) but ... I'm using CartoDB and wondering if there's a straightforward way to convert New York-Long Island State Plane coordinates to lat/long geometry en masse?

Happy to accept a pointer to documentation I should be reading.

Comment: Are you trying to reproject the table, or create new columns that hold the XY values of the points as LAT/LON (WGS84)?

Comment: I'm trying to populate `the_geom` with points. I was guessing the fastest path to that was to convert the State Plane coordinates, but I might be wrong?

Comment: Are you able to take this data into QGIS first then create a shapefile from the XY points, then reproject using QGIS to WGS84, then bring into CartoDB?

Comment: "able to" is a choice phrase. I'm assuming the answer is yes. I *have* QGIS, but I'm not super deft with it. So that's one solution, to figure out how to follow the steps you describe.

Comment: Here's a great tutorial on reprojecting data in QGIS, check section 1.3: http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely use QGIS to project state plane coordinates to WGS84 then import to CartoDB but you're adding unnecessary steps.

The last answer is correct except if you're converting from New York-Long Island State Plane you need to use SRID 2263. I think the above SRID is Mass State Plane.

Try this:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(xcoordinate, ycoordinate), 2263), 4326)
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE table SET the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(coord_x, coord_y), 2249), 4326)